# SQL SUBQUERY to rate poems according to style, somewhat tricky?

Tags: sql

This is about rating poems according to a parameter such as style.

I have 3 tables, poems, style and rates.

Poems and style are FK linked.

styles table contains id, poem_id and value (being value what the score given by readers)

Rates is just a reference table that contains a translation of what a digit rating means, say, 1 means very poor, 10 excellent.

Each poem can receive many ratings from different people, so finally what I need to do is sum up those ratings, get their average and group them by poem id. Cool, I achieve that almost, but what I am missing is one column where I need to indicate what rate belongs to which post, without which, of course I provide no useful info.

I have this:

```
select ratedesc
from rates
where rates.digit
IN (SELECT ROUND(AVG(styles.value))
    FROM styles
      join poems on styles.poems_id = poems.id
    GROUP BY poems.id)
```

which gets me a display like this:

```
Good
Standard
Excellent
Poor
```

so each of those adjectives is actually the avg of all the ratings for each poem expressed in a verbose and verbal way instead of just saying 5 or 8.
but, of course, I am missing to tell which poem do they refer to

I should be adding the poem_id, to the first select, but that requires changing completely the structure of the query, and this is what I am not achieving

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result. Also, tag your question with the correct dbms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the `AVG` of each `Poems` using a subquery and then do a `JOIN` on `Rates` to get the description:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.AvgStyle, r.RateDesc
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.id, ROUND(AVG(s.Value)) AS AvgStyle
    FROM Poems p
    INNER JOIN Styles s
        ON s.poems_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id
) t
INNER JOIN Rates r
    ON r.digit = t.AvgStyle
```

Comment: thank you both. Probably both answers were right, but I only got to use the one from Felix. What a genius, I would have never be able to reach this level on my own. I have a tendency to create questions beyond my knowledge.

Comment: You're gonna get there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
With value as
(
 Select po.id, ROUND(AVG(st.value)) value from Style st inner join
Poem po on st.poem_id = po.id GROUP BY po.id
)
Select val.id,ra.ratedesc from value val inner join rates ra on val.value = ra.value
```